# firing a js function when skrollr animation is complete

Tags: jquery, animation, skrollr

Has anyone had a need to fire a single function when a given Skrollr animation is complete? There's a "done" method but I found no explanation how to achieve this. Thanks in advance, and sorry there's no code to paste :-\

html:

```
<div
    data-0="background-color:rgb(0,0,255);"
    data-500="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);">
  WOOOT
</div>
```

js:

```
var s = skrollr.init({

    }
});
```

this is only the initiation of the plugin.

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Comment: So what exactly have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: I want to switch between 3 photos once an animation is complete. I found no explanation on the "done" method, as well as how to use all the advanced js features skrollr has. Basically all I need is some syntax...

Comment: You need to post your code, show what you have done.

Comment: ok, there's nothing much to it but here goes:

<div id="animPhone1" data-1500="transform:rotate(0deg);" data-2500="transform:rotate(0deg);" data-3500="transform:rotate(90deg);" data-3600="opacity:1;" data-3700="opacity:0;">

this is the basic syntax of an animation. there's no js at this point but the simple initiation of the Skrollr plugin:

var s = skrollr.init({

    }
});

Comment: Edit your question and format correctly... I'm not going to decipher that comment...

Comment: are you familiar with the Skrollr plugin?

Comment: nope... that doesn't mean your question shouldn't be formatted correctly though

Comment: The question seems pretty clear to me, he is asking if you can fire a function once the scroll animation is complete. So at 500 call a function to do something. I have the same issue.